# How to style React component in Angular 7 app

Tags: angular, reactjs

I have a problem with style React component in Angular 7.1 app.

I solve all problems with build app, bidirectional communication between Angular and ReactJS components but I can't solve a simple problem with style import.

Usually I use Less, but I can't import even .css file.

I try to use:

```
...
// @ts-ignore
import styles from './renderer.css';

...

class Renderer extends React.Component<IRenderer, any> {
    ...

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={styles.rendererbackground}>
               TEXT
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I try also:

```
// @ts-ignore
import './renderer.css';

<div className='rendererbackground'>
   TEXT
</div>
```

But only inline style works for me.

Do you have any idea how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Hi, can you explain how have you generated an angular application with react component integration?

Comment: @Joker I add a question and answer on StackOverflow for this, how to connect Angular app with ReactJS app, more hire: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54408694/connect-angular-application-with-reactjs-app/54408718#54408718

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have temporary workaround for this problem - I import style form my `react-renderer` component in Angular as `::ng-deep`,

```
::ng-deep {
    @import "../../react/renderer.less";
    @import "../../react/components/something/something.less";
}
```